# How to create a row with one cell in a expandible react table?

Tags: react-table, react-table-v7

I want to use useExpanded to create a subrow that stretches along all columns, similar to the screenshot. In the [react table example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-payne-dxs1d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js) it only provides expanded rows with the same columns like the table header.

[image]

```
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state: { expanded }
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns: userColumns,
      data
    },
    useExpanded // Use the useExpanded plugin hook
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `html` [colspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) attribute on the `td` element to the number of cells in the row.

```
<tr>
 <td colspan="3">Extra: cdd</td>
</tr>
```

Here is a good starting point. [See the CSB](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-forked-wcoii?file=/src/App.js)

```
<tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
  {rows.map((row, i) => {
    prepareRow(row);
    return (
      <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
        {!row.canExpand && <td colSpan={3}>{row.cells[1].value}</td>}
        {row.canExpand &&
          row.cells.map((cell) => {
            return (
              <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
            );
          })}
      </tr>
    );
  })}
</tbody>
```

Comment: How can this be done inside the react-table-configuration

Comment: I added a csb for you to see